# Getting the end of scroll event angularjs ionic (once scroll is stopped)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am not able to get the end of scroll event angularjs,ionic and the worst part is , its working fine in browser but not in android and iOS devices.

Here is my codepen link:
http://codepen.io/sudan_1993/pen/BowzbN

HTML:

```
 <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing='false'>
 <ion-list>      
       <div class="card" collection-repeat="product in products" scroll="atNewProduct($index)" scroll-item="atNewProduct($index)" scrollable>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class="col col-25">
            <img src={{product.ImagePath}}style="width:70px;height:70px"></img>
          </div>

         </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

JS:

```
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

starter.directive('scroll', function ($parse, $document, $window) {
var _ = $window._;
var verge = $window.verge;
var visibleElements = [];
// alert(JSON.stringify(verge) + '\n' + _ + '\n' + visibleElements[0]);
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: -1,
    scope: {
        scroll: '&',
        scrollItem: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var debounced = _.debounce(function() {

            // You might need a different test,
            // perhaps including the height of the element,
            // or using verge "rectangle" function
            var visible = verge.inViewport(element);

            var index = visibleElements.indexOf(scope.scrollItem);
            var previouslyVisible = (index != -1);
            if (visible && !previouslyVisible) {
                visibleElements.push(scope.scrollItem);
                scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.scroll({item:scope.scrollItem});
                });
            }
            if (!visible && previouslyVisible) {

              visibleElements.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }, 1000);
        angular.element($document).on('scroll', debounced);
        if (verge.inViewport(element)) {
            visibleElements.push(element);
        }

    }
};
});

 starter.directive('scrollable', ['$document', '$window', function ($document, $window ) { 
return {
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element($document).bind('scroll', function() { //i guess the problem is with this line
        console.log("scrollable-------------");
        // detect if scroll has stop and execute a function  
        clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                alert("Stopped");
            }, 250) );   
    });
}
};
}])

starter.controller('plpCntrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.atNewProduct = function(item) {
  console.log(item);//able to get the index of ng-repeater present in the screen
}
 });
```

The atNewProduct function is getting executed many times until the scroll is finished.Can anyone suggest me how to get the end of scroll event and get the index of that particular item present on the screen.

and more over i am getting an error message saying touch.webkitRaidusX is deprecated and will be removed in M47,around NOV 2015.